# Python OpenCV import error with python 3.5

Tags: python, opencv

I am having some difficulties installing opencv with python 3.5.

I have linked the cv files, but upon `import cv2` I get an error saying `ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyCObject_Type` or more specifically:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 /Users/Jamie/Desktop/tester/test.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/Jamie/Desktop/tester/test.py", line 2, in 
>       import cv
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv.py", line 1, in 
>       from cv2.cv import *
>   ImportError:dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyCObject_Type
>     Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2.so
>     Expected in: flat namespace
>    in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2.so

I have linked cv.py and cv2.so from location `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12_2/lib/python2.7/site-packages` correctly into `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin`

Would anybody be able to help please?

Thanks very much

Comment: Are you trying to load an opencv compiled for Python 2 using Python 3.5 ? It won't work. I documented here how I compiled opencv3 for Python 3 a few month ago, if it helps: https://github.com/julienpalard/grid-finder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer - follow the instructions on [this website](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/29/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-osx/) BUT you have to change to the version of python you are using.

Also, I didn't bother with the virtual environments.

And lastly cv2.so is actually called cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so in the build/lib folder that you make.

Then it works.

Comment: For the future, you could also just create a symlink with `ln -s cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so cv2.so` so you can import it  using `import cv2`. :-)

Comment: Hey gglasses, how do I create a symlink as you said?

Comment: ln -s cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so cv2.so

Answer (score 6):

No need to change the python version, you can just use the pip command
open cmd ( admin mode) and type

pip install opencv-python

Answer (score 0):

Great answer JamieS, I also followed that website. I tried to make the whole process repeatable with these make targets..

```
opencv-build:
    source $(VENV_DIR)/bin/activate && \
    cd $(OPENCV_SRC) && \
    mkdir -p build && \
    cd build && \
    cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(realpath $(BUILD_DIR)) \
    -D PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=$(realpath $(VENV_DIR)/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include) \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=$(realpath $(OPENCV_CONTRIB_SRC)/modules) \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..  && \
    make -j4 -C .
```

To make it appear in python3 virtual env however you need to do this then:

```
so-copy:
    cp $(realpath $(OPENCV_SRC)/build/lib/cv2.so) $(realpath $(VENV_DIR)/lib/python3.5/site-packages/)
    cp $(realpath $(OPENCV_SRC)/build/lib/python3/cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so) $(realpath $(VENV_DIR)/lib/python3.5/site-packages/)
```

Then you can test if it works..

```
import cv2  # Imports without problems...
```

I think for osx the cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so is the only one you need, but I just copied both.